# Fetching records from a table with more than a million entries. How to do this fast using java?

Tags: java, mysql

I have a MySQL table with 27 columns and more than 1 million rows. I want to fetch the complete data from the table, which makes my query -  select * from table;

I do this through java Prepared statmennts and ResultSet. How can I optimize this operation. Some kind of batching will be helpful or should I proceed with some other technique?

Could you please advise.

Comment: seriously? you are trying to fetch million of records? you should look into pagination or batches

Comment: For what purpose? If it's for an update, the best bet is not to fetch them at all, but to express the update as a single UPDATE statement, and have all the work done by the database. Transporting a million rows back and forth cannot possibly be fast.

Comment: Your question is too vague to have an answer at this point.  We need to understand what you're going to do with the rows of data (read only? update?)

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I want to fetch the data from one mysql table, add them into MongoDB through Java.

Comment: OK, now why through Java? You should be able to accomplish that via dump and restore tools.

Comment: @EJP - This is the technique which is in place as of now. I can discuss with the senior team members about using dump and restore tools.

Comment: It's not 'in place now' if you're asking how best to do it.